# Should a code review be different for front-end web developers?

Tags: web-development, code-reviews

Web developers code in a minimum of four languages (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and a server-side language), must produce a working result in several different browser implementations, and may work on the top of a custom software stack that they don't control.

- How should a code review take these things into account?
- Should a code review include all parts of a front-end project (HTML and CSS as
  well), or just focus on the logic?
- How should a code review handle workarounds for browser- or stack-specific problems?

Comment: One of the easiest and most objective things to check during a review of the front-end code is how well it passes checkers such as jshint, jslint, and the W3C validators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code reviews should cover all the code - that certainly includes the JavaScript and HTML and probably even the CSS.

If you don't have another person proficient in all areas, break the review down into sections so that each can be viewed by another language expert. If you don't have another expert someone will have to become proficient "enough" to be able to ask sensible questions.

If there are any workarounds in the code then these should be checked more thoroughly than the the rest of the code to ensure that they only fire when they should and don't have an adverse affect on the rest of the code.

Comment: Agreed. We have multiple reviews that can be flagged by context and each type of review goes to that team's team of reviewers: Custom Code, Database, UI, Global, Security and Architecture. Our source control monitors the type of files that are checked in and we have rules that then flag certain reviews as required before code can move to the next environment.

Answer (score 1):

User Interface review should be part of code review for web applications. The reviewers check list should include -
a) Consistency of web presentation across your web application (use same style buttons through out your application) 
b) How is the user experience on the your web application (pop up or inline edit is better? or can we reduce number of clicks user has to make?)

In larger firms I have worked with, there are teams specialized for user interface review (UI experts or creative services). However, the developer/reviewer still has the primary responsibility of CSS/HTML/JS. The specialized UI teams are there just to give suggestions and sign off the application look and feel.

I am not sure if I understand your third question correctly. If the question is related to target web browser - If you know your end users very well (say an intranet environment), you know for which bowers you should test you application. But if your application is available on public Internet , then extensive testing is the way to go. I find this link useful - http://www.zdnetasia.com/testing-web-applications-with-multiple-browsers-62036598.htm